# I'm a newbie and having problems with a rounding here

Tags: python

I've used the rounding in another portion of my homework, but I'm having issues with this one...

```
pred_weight = []

pred_weight = [(length[i]*0.6)-5.2 for i in range (0,len(weight))]

round(pred_weight,4)

print (round(int(pred_weight)))
```

**The error it kicks out is...**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-275-9d2218701582> in <module>
      3 pred_weight = [(length[i]*0.6)-5.2 for i in range (0,len(weight))]
      4 
----> 5 round(pred_weight,4)
      6 print (round(int(pred_weight)))
      7 

TypeError: type list doesn't define __round__ method
```

I've tried setting it up as an int, but got nowhere with that.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Use [np.round()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're applying the round method to the list. It should be applied to individual elements in your list.
Something, like this:

```
pred_weight = [round(i,4) for i in pred_weight]
```

you can apply round here also:

```
pred_weight = [round(((length[i]*0.6)-5.2),4) for i in range(len(weight))]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
pred_weight = []

pred_weight = [(length[i]*0.6)-5.2 for i in range (0,len(weight))]

for i in pred_weight:
    print (round(i,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do something like this

```
round(pred_weight[0])
```

You're trying to round a list object, which looks something like this in theory

```
my_list = [0, 5.4, 10.2, 42.7, 15.3]
```

You can't round a list object, you have to pass a number through. So if I wanted the second index, which is 5 in this list, i would do `my_list[1]` to return 5.4 and then I can round that number.